# Server side route to download file

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've got a server side route I'm using to download a file. This is called from a client side button click and everything is working fine. However, once the button has been clicked once it will not work again until another route is loaded and you go back. How can I code it so that the button can be clicked multiple times and the server side route be fired each time?

My button code looks like this...

```
'click #view_document_download': function (event, tmpl) {
   Router.go('/download_document/' + this._id);
}
```

And my server side route looks like this...

```
Router.route('/download_document/:_id', function () {

  //Get the file record to download
  var file = files.findOne({_id: this.params._id});

  //Function to take a cfs file and return a base64 string
  var getBase64Data = function(file2, callback) {
    var readStream = file2.createReadStream();
    var buffer = [];
    readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
      buffer.push(chunk);
    });
    readStream.on('error', function(err) {
      callback(err, null);
    });
    readStream.on('end', function() {
      callback(null, buffer.concat()[0].toString('base64'));
    });
  };

  //Wrap it to make it sync    
  var getBase64DataSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(getBase64Data);

  //Get the base64 string
  var base64str = getBase64DataSync(file);

  //Get the buffer from the string
  var buffer = new Buffer(base64str, 'base64');

  //Create the headers
  var headers = {
    'Content-type': file.original.type,
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + file.original.name
  };

  this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
  this.response.end(buffer, 'binary');

}, { where: 'server' });
```

Answer (score 1):

use `a` element instead of js 'click' event
**page html**

```
<a href="/download_document/{{_id}}" download="true" target="_blank"></a>
```

**page js in server**

```
Router.route("/download_document/:fileId", function(){
    var file = files.findOne({_id: this.params.fileId});
    var contentFile = //file text
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=file.txt"
    };
    this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
    this.response.end(contentFile);
  },
  {where: "server", name: "download"}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just return an Object from your Server via a method and form it to a file on the client side? if possible..

To create a file on the client side is really simple, and you don't have to deal with Routers at this point.

```js
     function outputFile(filename, data) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'}); // !note file type..
        if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        }
        else{
            var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
            elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            elem.download = filename;        
            document.body.appendChild(elem)
            elem.click();        
            document.body.removeChild(elem);
        }
     }
     
     function getContentAndOutputFile() {
       var content = document.getElementById('content').value;

       outputFile('file.txt', content);
     }
```

```html
<input id="content" value="test content"/>
<button onClick="getContentAndOutputFile()">Create File</button>
```

Comment: I could do that but I have a working solution with this server side and it's just the route that I'd like to reset each time. I'm more interested to know if this is possible.

Comment: Also, I'd be interested to understand the performance impact of your solution over a standard server side download?

Comment: Well, regarding Performance its simple, you download the file once to the client. Next Time clicking it just Takes the Same file, without stressing the Server